# Use of error bars around values indicating standard error

Tags: standard-error

[image]

1. Would like to know what's the use of putting error bars indicating standard error and isn't it better to interpret with margin of errors ($±2SE$) instead?
2. Does it make sense to put standard errors around the first value where *time=0* and the *mean change in score=0*?, or can it be a mistake?

Reference: Raymond W. Lam et al, Efficacy of Bright Light Treatment, Fluoxetine, and the Combination in Patients With Nonseasonal Major Depressive Disorder: A Randomized Clinical Trial *JAMA Psychiatry* doi:10.1001/jamapsychiatry.2015.2235

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that even $\pm 2$ SE is an approximation that may be slightly too high or too low depending on sample size. Graphically that won't usually matter much, although it might be considered careless or cavalier.

Otherwise there are at least 3 conventions for error bars (setting aside box plots with said boxes showing quartiles, which are occasionally confused or conflated with error bars), namely using (1) standard deviation SD, (2) standard error SE or (3) a confidence interval for what is being estimated, usually at a 95% level.

Setting aside any suspicion that authors are being optimistic about their data, what is essential to me is that authors make clear what they are doing, and so which convention they are using.

Even showing a confidence interval is prone to misinterpretation, as adjacent bars that don't overlap do not necessarily imply difference at conventional levels.

I haven't looked at the specific reference and don't want to get into having to work out exactly what the authors did and whether it is correct, a good idea, or whatever. Why not engage with them directly?

Answer (score 2):

> Does it make sense to put standard errors around the first value where time=0 and the mean change in score=0?, or is it a mistake?

As I understand it (haven't read the paper), at time 0 the mean change is zero by construction. However, also that mean has its own dispersion so I think it's sensible to have error bars there. (I wonder why the at time 0 the bars are plotted only in the lower range).

Unrelated: Instead of a legend box I would have put the four labels directly next to their lines so you don't have to visually match lines to colours or symbols.

Comment: At time 0 the bars are plotted only in the lower range, beacuse the change in scores are rather a decrease than an increase?